# Real Time Face and eye tracking using video processing with AForge.net

Tags: opencv, video, image-processing, emgucv, aforge

**Please Guide me:**
I am going to make my Final year project in image processing using the concept of real time video processing.

Project will contain the following **Task**:

- Capture the video in real time.
- Track the face and eyes pupal in real time.
- If eyes are closed then alarm.
  Now i confused about to which library should be used by me **AForge.net or openCv?**
  Does **AForge.net** support the real time face and eyes tracking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though AForge is a very powerful library i'd rather use Accord.NET as it implements all AForge libraries + additional, and unlike AForge , there is still some active development

Now , between choosing for OpenCV and Accord,  I'd personally recommend to go instead for OpenCV or any of its wrappers. My Rationale :

- Stronger developers community
- More updates
- More algorithms  supported
- More flexibility
- Supports more video codecs and formats

BTW,  both OpenCV and Accord have already implemented Viola-Jones and Eigenfaces algorithms , which are commonly used for face detection.

Comment: Thanks For this help full information

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on the fact if you can use built in OpenCV features. Face and eyes tracking in OpenCV is an easy task if you use Haar Cascade. Please, read this article. It explain the idea:
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html
P.S. There are multiple wrappers that allow to use OpenCV with C# (EmguCV), Python, Java. So, you are not limited to create your app only in C++.

Comment: It would help if you also gave a small explanation of what the link contains, as the link may change in the future.